# trying to understand jsonp with the flickr example

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp

I'm trying to get my head around how I can make json request to a json file stored on my server from jsfiddle.

html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="images">  
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

jquery:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.shopsheep.com/groupon/json/test.json?jsoncallback=?", function(data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
            $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
            if (i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });


$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
        $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
        if (i == 0) return false;
    });
});
```

I downloaded the flicker json file and uploaded it to my server as test.json.  If I paste it in the browser it returns just as the flicker file.

However when I try to display the image only the original flicker example is working?  Any idea why this is the case?

[http://jsfiddle.net/stofke/DJQ5g](http://jsfiddle.net/stofke/DJQ5g/)

**Ok I have found out how to do this.  The getJSON function adds a random
named callback functionname to jsoncallback=?  something like this
`jQuery160188050875203142_1309437718540&_=1309437718551`
In order to wrap your json file with  this callbackfunction you need of course to know the name of this function, so if you convert your jsonfile into a php file than you can get the callbackfunctionname like this:**

```
<?php echo $_GET["jsoncallback"];?>(
    ADD JSON CONTENT HERE 
)
```

**This php file will get the name of the callbackfunction via a GET variable and wraps the json content with it.  This way it works fine.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON file missed function name. It should start with function name.
If you see here http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json, it starts with `jsonFlickrFeed`.

Your JSON should be like this:

```
callback({
        "title": "Uploads from everyone",
        "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/",
        "description": "",
        "modified": "2011-06-29T21:43:16Z",
        "generator": "http://www.flickr.com/",
        "items": [
       {....
```

Maybe you need to understand more about JSONP. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: Still not clear to me.  the jsonFlickrFeed is indeed there if you open the link with Firefox however with Chrome it's not displayed.
Whatever callbackfunction I add it returns as callback undefined.

Comment: Ah ok I see with jquery call I need to dynamically generate the wrapped json with the callbackfunction supplied by jquery